# Using ps and watch to observe parent and child process

Tags: terminal, process, ps, watch

I got a parent and a child process running, I know their IDs.

How do I utilize 'ps' and 'watch' to filter them out, so that I can see their used CPU times?

I tried 'watch ps -u USERNAME', but as you can imagine there are a lot more processes than the desired ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the PIDs are e.g. 340 and 520, then you can try the following:

```
$ watch --interval 2 --difference "ps -p 340,520 -o pid,ppid,%cpu,cputime"
```

Here `watch` will mark the difference of outputs running with 2 seconds interval, here we have used the output formatting `-o` option to get only process ID (pid), parent process ID (ppid), percentage of cpu utilization (%cpu) and the cpu time (cputime).

Check `man ps` for more `ps` output formatting options.